# Cascade on delete sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, html

Im working on a small website that involves the use of databases, I'm using this two tables to users, in the first table i add the users and his information, and in the second one I add only the `user id` the `course id`.

My question is how can I add the `cascade on delete`, in which table?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `students` (
  `studentid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fname` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `studentcode` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `courseid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`studentid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=27 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `idtables` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `courseid` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `studentid` char(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=43 ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define this behaviour in a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `idtables` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `courseid` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `studentid` char(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY fk_students_id (studentid)
    REFERENCES students (id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=43 ;
```

Comment: what the fk_students_id means ?

Comment: @CarlosPerez, it's the constraint name.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `FORIEGN KEY` referencing to `students` table `studentid` with `ON DELETE CASCADE` option like below

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `idtables` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `courseid` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `studentid` char(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   CONSTRAINT FK1 FORIEGN KEY(studentid) REFERENCES students(studentid) <-- Here
   ON DELETE CASCADE <-- HERE
)
```

Comment: It is the same if I use studentid or courseid, to do the cascade delete ?

Comment: @CarlosPerez, NO you can't reference to `courseid` since that's not defined as primary key in student table.

Comment: @Sammitch, you can try, it works as well fine.

Comment: @Rahul ooh I see that, so to do the delete on cascade I have to use the primary

Comment: @CarlosPerez, that's right, I mean if you are creating a FK constraint, it should point to PK in other table. Moreover, in your student table studentid is of type int(11) then why in your idtables you declare studentid as char(64) .. declare it as int(11) as well.